# How to return key value of enums from web api to angular 8

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-webapi, angular8

I need to return a collection with pair of enums like [SectionEnum, StatusEnum]. I have tried using a Dictionary:

```
Dictionary<SectionEnum, StatusEnum>
```

but it is returns as a string, int, that may be good enough, but then I am not sure how to convert it to enums in Angular.

I am using web.api core and Angular 8

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: Create the enum in Typescript.https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are most probably using the `httpClient.get<T>` format to access the api.

That being the case you should create the T type in typescript. When you get the result back from the api (which will either send the int value by default or some string value) you can use the typescript enum to be type safe on the client side.

```
export enum SectionEnum {

}

export enum StatusEnum {

}
```

The enum types are just integers limited by range (well that's a simplification but that's their essence).

Now to create a useful return type, like an array of key value pairs, you need to try something like this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Mobile?id=P1SeP2#code-editor